# how to change the date format of my bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, date, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i am new in bootstrap datetimepicker. How would i change its defaut time format?. I have a default date format of mysql (yyyy/mm/dd). I want also to change my datetimepicker so that it co-inside my database date format.

Here is the bootstrap date time picker:

```
<form id="date">
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pbdate">Birthdate:</label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pabdate" name="pabdate" placeholder="Birthdate" required>
              <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
              </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
</form>
```

here is the format i want:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'    // pass here your desired format
 });
```

Here is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_date/mydate",
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#date').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
     }
   )};
```

When i `var_dump` it in my controller because i am using codeigniter the output is still `mm/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'    // pass here your desired format
 });
```

**Note:** Database default format of date is D-M-Y

You can change it in controller function to database supported format like:

```
$DB_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date_picker_date));
```

Comment: what if i am in this situation sir.

In my <form> i made it in ajax
data: $('#frm_reg').serialize(),

value still string(10) "12/28/2016"
i change it already to format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'    // pass here your desired format

Answer (score 2):

check this 
See http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

format must be

```
 $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss' // change format here
  });
```

Comment: what if i am in this situation sir.

In my <form> i made it in ajax
data: $('#frm_reg').serialize(),

value still string(10) "12/28/2016"
i change it already to format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'    // pass here your desired format

Comment: can i add ajax in jsfiddle ? i am currently in codeigniter

Comment: you can see left side option for ajax also

Comment: i'll edit my question. i cant run jsfiddle in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **input type="text"** set **type="date"**. Then in SQL set datatype `smalldatetime`. Else you any specific format means set datatype in SQL as `varchar` and create stored procedure then convert it as your need in the stored procedure use this `convert(varchar(11), dcreate_dt, (106)) as column_name`